# Is it possible to perform all these string validations in a single regexp?

Tags: regex, go

I'm trying to figure out if I can combine all these statements into a single regexp check, but not being particularly well versed in regex doing it in these separate checks is the best I've got so far:

```
func ValidatePwd(pwd string) error {
    pwdRuneCount := utf8.RuneCountInString(pwd)
    containsAtLeastOneDigit, err := regexp.MatchString("[0-9]", pwd)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    containsAtLeastOneLowercase, err := regexp.MatchString("[a-z]", pwd)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    containsAtLeastOneUppercase, err := regexp.MatchString("[A-Z]", pwd)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    containsAtLeastOneNonWordChar, err := regexp.MatchString(`[\W]`, pwd)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if pwdRuneCount < PwdMinRuneCount || pwdRuneCount > PwdMaxRuneCount || !containsAtLeastOneDigit || !containsAtLeastOneLowercase || !containsAtLeastOneUppercase || !containsAtLeastOneNonWordChar {
        return PwdErr
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Since Go regexp does not support lookarounds, you cannot combine them all into 1 regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, but it would be ugly. A single regexp would have to contain 24 subexpressions of the form `[0-9].*[a-z].*[A-Z].*\W` to match each of the possible orders in which the four required character types could occur. The way you're doing it now is much better.

By the way, instead of checking for errors from your `MatchString` calls (which means that the regular expression was invalid), you should probably precompile them with `regexp.MustCompile`, which panics if the regexp is invalid.